# RegexReplace produces an error

Tags: google-sheets, regex

I have two sheets of data as per below:

```
╔═══════════╦══════╦══════════════╗
║ SheetName ║ Cell ║  CellValue   ║
╠═══════════╬══════╬══════════════╣
║ Sheet1    ║ B1   ║ ='sheet2'!A2 ║
║ Sheet2    ║ A2   ║ 0576543 ABC  ║
╚═══════════╩══════╩══════════════╝
```

This produces the output `0576543 ABC` in `B1`

I want the value in `B1` to replace the text after the space with `xxx`.

The value in `B1` should be `0576543 xxx`.

I have tried this Regex but it produces an error.

`=REGEXREPLACE("'sheet2'!A2", " .*", "xxx")`

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I have edited your question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2):

The issue in this case appears to be that you put double quotes and single quotes around the cell reference, try this, should fix it.

```
=REGEXREPLACE(sheet2!A2, " .*", "xxx")
```

Answer (score -1):

In my version the error was produced by the commas (,) i had to use semicolons (;)